# Higher order corrections in relativistic hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, hamiltonian, approximations

This is a question I came to while reading Srednicki. My overall goal is to understand quantum/QFT in the end so that doing math research in physics-adjacent topics seems more meaningful. I am a mathematician, not a physics student.

Consider a single, spinless, non-relativistic particle with no forces acting on it. The hamiltonian for the system is

$$H=\frac{p\cdot p}{2m}.$$

Srednicki claims that the obvious way to generalize this to a relativistic system is to take

$$H=+\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}.$$

Is this true simply because $H$ describes the sum of kinetic and potential energy of the system, and because this gives the relativistic energy-momentum relation?

Srednicki then expands this in inverse powers of $c$:

$$H=mc^2+\frac{p\cdot p}{2m}+\cdots.$$

The way I am conceptualizing this is as follows: If there is no momentum, then the only energy must come from mass, so we have the rest energy $mc^2$ as a term. The second term is the same as the non-relativistic $H$, and the rest of the terms are called higher-order corrections. Can you explain what the higher-order corrections are doing? From a mathematical point of view, if $H=+\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}$ is the correct hamiltonian, then expanding just reveals their presence. But from the point of view of trying to conceptualize what is happening, this doesn't satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: Yes to "relativistic energy-momentum relation". The Taylor expansion has no conceptual meaning, except that it works, and it gives the correct low momentum limit.